# Check the checkboxes using onclick by javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am stuck in a very stupid problem. I am trying to select all the checkboxes which I am creating dynamically using a loop in a table. In the head of the table I have a checkbox and I want to select all the checkboxes in the table after clicking that checkbox in the head.
Here is my code.

```
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
        <th class="spacer_100 align_ctr tooltip_trigger">
        Change Status <input type="checkbox" name="sample" onclick="selectAll()">
        </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

          <?php foreach ($users as $user) { ?>
          <tr>
          <td class="align_ctr" style="text-align: center">
           <input type="checkbox" name="current_status[]" value="1"/>
          </td>
          </tr>
          <?php } ?> 
      </tbody>
     </table>
```

Here is the javascript code:

```
    function selectAll() {
      var checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
       for(var i=1; i<checkboxes.length;i++) {
        if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox') {
        checkboxes[i].checked = 'true';
       }
      }
     }
```

I don't know what is wrong with this code, I am not able to select checkboxes.

Thanks

Comment: [Works for me.](http://jsfiddle.net/bG3mm/)

Comment: by the way, where's your foreach end tag  `<?php endforeach; ?>` ?

Comment: I have the closing brackets of foreach in my actual code, I just put it in the code above, but I am still not sure why all the checkboxes are not selecting.

Comment: I am using codeigniter, do I need to make any changes because of that?

Answer (score 0):

it works fine, but your code:

```
var checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
```

selects the main checkbox as well, try doing:

```
var checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for(var i=0; i<checkboxes.length;i++) { //start from 0
    if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox' && checkboxes[i].name == 'current_status[]') {
        checkboxes[i].checked = 'true';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about try this code?

Change to

```
 Change Status <input type="checkbox" name="sample" onclick="selectAll(this)">
```

and following function

```
function SelectAll(CheckBoxControl){
    var i;
    for (i=0; i < document.forms[0].elements.length; i++){
       if ((document.forms[0].elements[i].type == 'checkbox') &&  
         (document.forms[0].elements[i].name.indexOf('current_status[]') > -1)){
         document.forms[0].elements[i].checked = CheckBoxControl.checked;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope, I checked using breakpoints in the javascript function, it is calling every thing properly but still I don't see checkboxes selected. Is there a possibility that it selecting the checkboxes but just it is not showing there as selected because after running this, I need to click twice on these checkboxes to make it selected.